# Escrow contract that pays out to my wallet. Should I hard code my wallet address in the contract?

Tags: ethereum

I'm writing an escrow contract that pays out `0.01%` to my wallet of the total amount that both parties deposit into my contract.

This is how I make a bit of money to cover the costs of maintaining both the web and mobile app.

Would it be a bad idea to hardcode my wallet address into the contract? So that if the transaction between both parties is successful, the small fee can be sent to my wallet.

Comment: It's a bad idea because something might need you to migrate to a new wallet. You can use `Owner` pattern from OpenZeppelin to make the owner of the contract transferable.